# How to correctly use set_prior() in brms with values extracted from a matrix, e.g. prior(normal(priors[i,1], priors[i,2]))

Tags: r, matrix, regression, brms

I'd like to create a set of parameters for use in a **brms** model in **R**:

```
library(brms)

tmp <- prior(normal(10,2), nlpar = "x")
```

Ideally I'd like to extract the values for each prior (e.g. `normal(10,2)`) from an imported matrix, for example:

```
priors <- cbind(c(10,20,30,40), c(2,4,6,8))

i <- 1
tmp <- prior(normal(priors[i,1], priors[i,2]), nlpar = "x")
```

However, this gives the following output:

```
#b_x ~ normal(priors[i, 1], priors[i, 2])
```

instead of the numeric values:

```
#b_x ~ normal(10, 2)
```

I realize this is probably pretty basic, but I can't figure out the correct way to do this. I've tried:

```
prior(normal(as.numeric(priors[i,1]), as.numeric(priors[i,2])), nlpar = "x")
prior(normal(as.list(priors[i,1]), as.list(priors[i,2])), nlpar = "x")
prior(normal(paste(priors[i,1]), paste(priors[i,2])), nlpar = "x")
prior(normal(get(priors[i,1]), paste(get[i,2])), nlpar = "x")
```

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong here? extracting by position [,] seems to work for other functions, e.g., `lm(priors[,1]~priors[,2])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to evaluate `priors[i, 1]` and `priors[i, 2]` when they are passed to `prior()`.

```
priors <- cbind(c(10, 20, 30, 40), c(2, 4, 6, 8))

i <- 1

## use `do.call()`
do.call("prior",
        list(prior = call("normal", priors[i, 1], priors[i, 2]),
             nlpar = "x"))
#b_x ~ normal(10, 2)

## use `eval(call())`
eval(call("prior", call("normal", priors[i, 1], priors[i, 2]), nlpar = "x"))
#b_x ~ normal(10, 2)
```

While this works, as I read `?prior`, I find that it is recommended to specify distribution as a string. Therefore, the following also works.

```
## I used %d because values in `priors` matrix are integers
## in general, it is safer to use %f for real numbers
eval(call("prior",
          sprintf("normal(%d, %d)", priors[i, 1], priors[i, 2]),
          nlpar = "x"))
#b_x ~ normal(10, 2)
```

---

**Note:**

I am also a newbie with **brms**, so I honestly think the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72823132/4891738) more native/natural to the package. (This is the benefit of learning by answering questions; I always get useful feedback from peers.)

As said, it is the recommended way, because it is the **brms** equivalent of passing prior hyperparameters as data to a **Stan** model.

Comment: On the other hand, this is a more general solution that will work in other situations besides brms.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is with the function `brms::stanvar()`. Take a look at its [man page here](http://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/stanvar.html). This is advantageous because you can change the prior within `stanvar()` and refit the model without having to recompile it. Because **brms** is a wrapper for Stan, this is the equivalent of passing hyperparameters of a prior distribution as part of the `data` block in a Stan model.

Each call to `stanvar()` takes two arguments, the value and a string which is the name of the variable that can be used later on inside `prior()`. Then combine each individual variable together using `+` and pass that to the `stanvars` argument of `brm()`.

For your example, you could do like so:

```
prior_params <- stanvar(priors[i, 1], 'prior_mean') + stanvar(priors[i, 2], 'prior_sd')

x_prior <- prior(normal(prior_mean, prior_sd), nlpar = 'x')

brm(..., prior = x_prior, stanvars = prior_params)
```

*Edit*: You may pass a vector of hyperparameters to the first argument of `stanvar()` and then index the vector in your call to `prior()`. Example:

```
my_prior_means <- c(0, 1, 2)
my_prior_sds <- c(1, 2, 3)

prior_params <- stanvar(my_prior_means, 'prior_mean') + stanvar(my_prior_sds, 'prior_sd')

abc_prior <- c(
  prior(normal(prior_mean[1], prior_sd[1]), nlpar = 'a'),
  prior(normal(prior_mean[2], prior_sd[2]), nlpar = 'b'),
  prior(normal(prior_mean[3], prior_sd[3]), nlpar = 'c')
)

dt <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))

brm(
  bf(y ~ a / (1 + exp(-b*x + c)), a + b + c ~ 1, nl = TRUE), 
  prior = abc_prior, 
  stanvars = prior_params,
  data = dt
)
```

Comment: Curious why this was unaccepted, as it is the recommended way of passing prior hyperparameters programmatically to a brm model

Comment: I don't see how this easily generalizes for many different prior distributions. For example it seems that the OP would have to define a "prior_mean_1", "prior_mean_2", etc.

Comment: You could pass a vector as the first argument to `stanvar` and then index it when you create the `prior()`. I will edit the answer to mention this.

Comment: Thanks! It still seems the brms `prior` objects must be created individually, but I'm not sure if vectorizing that is possible. I just compare to rstanarm where I can easily do `prior = normal(location = locations, scale = scales)`, where `locations` and `scales` are vectors